# Generate logs using SQL Server profiler to show SQL stmt with values passed for actions performed on database from web application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-profiler

I have created a web appliaction in C# using ASP.NET MVC and SQL Server 2016 as my database. Now whenever I perform any action in the front end of my web application, some DML operations are performed on the database table of my database.

My requirement is to log all those DML operation performed on the database with respective SQL statements and values passed. I was told that we can achieve this using SQL Server Profiler. I tried following the steps mentioned in https://www.codeproject.com/articles/21371/sql-server-profiler-step-by-step  I could get the SQL statements but not values am I missing something or is there another way to do.

Comment: Clarify: do you need the values of parameters passed (which Profiler *should* capture, if you're capturing the proper events and columns), or do you need the result sets of the statements (which Profiler will not capture)?

Comment: Sir I need the values that are passed in case of stored procedures it shows @1,@2etc rather than showing values

Comment: The `RPC:Completed` event definitely includes the parameter values. If the application is issuing the stored procedure call as an ad-hoc dynamic query rather than a proper RPC call, you'll need to capture all the `SQL:StmtCompleted` (and/or `SP:StmtCompleted` events for stored procedures calling other stored procedures). Because this includes everything, and that's a lot, you may be able to filter just by statements containing `sp_executesql` or at least `exec`.

Comment: Sir the RPC: Completed event shows all the parameter values. Thank you Sir